# Replace everything in the text file after IP Address

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file in which I have something like this-

```
10.2.57.44      56538154    3028
120.149.20.197  28909678    3166
10.90.158.161   869126135   6025
```

In that text file, I have around 400,000 rows exactly as above. I have opened the same text file in Notepad++. I needed a way to remove everything from that text file leaving only IP Address (first column in the above text file is IP Address). I think, I can do that using Regular Expression. And notepad++ also has the option of using Regular Expression. But not sure what regular expression I need to use. Can anyone help me out here?

So output should be something like this-

```
10.2.57.44
120.149.20.197
10.90.158.161
```

Comment: Welcome to Regular Expressions!  You're gonna love it, especially with Notepad++ on your screen.  Be sure and check out the regex-related plug-ins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `\s.*` with nothing! A regex needs only to match what it needs to match, and what you want to match here is a space followed by anything (thus leaving the IP address alone, since it starts the line and there are no spaces in it)

Alternatively, if you have them, this is even better done with a classical Unix command:

```
sed -i 's/\s.*//' thefile
```

Example:

```
$ cat <<EOF | sed 's/\s.*//'
> 10.2.57.44      56538154    3028
> 120.149.20.197  28909678    3166
> 10.90.158.161   869126135   6025
> EOF
10.2.57.44
120.149.20.197
10.90.158.161
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Find:

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*
```

And replace with:

```
\1
```

The parentheses will capture that part of the regex to a variable, which is named `\1` (since it is the first capture block in the regex). The rest of the line is not captured but simply thrown out by the replace operation.

Comment: This will work but is basically not needed: you don't need to match the IP address at all, since what you want is to replace what is after it (with nothing). Matching what is after it is much more simple.

Comment: Sure, but I prefer the verbose version because it leaves alone any other text that might be in the file. See it as defensive programming with regexes.

Comment: The OP says that all lines are exactly as the above. As such, matching the IP address is of no help ;) See my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have gawk or something:

```
gawk "{print $1}" filename
```

In linux(bash) usage of `awk` will look like following:

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ cat stack 
10.2.57.44      56538154    3028
120.149.20.197  28909678    3166
10.90.158.161   869126135   6025
suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ cat stack | awk '{ print $1 }'
10.2.57.44
120.149.20.197
10.90.158.161
```