# Notepad++ IP Address highlighting language

Tags: ip, notepad++

I need to highlight IP address (IPv4) in Notepad++ while examining server logs. I tried to define a new language with some rules, but without actual success. Does anyone know how to do it?

format is standard, for example:
192.168.0.1 where numbers are from 0-255 separated with dots.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from : http://ehc.ac/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/90404ea1/?limit=25

So, to highlight ANY VALID IPv4 address ONLY, in the current text, follow the method below:

- Open the Search dialog ( CTRL + F )
- Click on the fourth tab, named Mark
- Fill in the regex, below, in the Find what field:

  \b(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(.(?1)){3}\b
- Check the Bookmark line option
- Check the Purge for each search option
- Check the Wrap around option
- Select the Regular expression search mode
- Click on the Mark All button

^^So i tried it, and it didn't work, and then i spent half an hour trawling the net for a decent reg exp.

Finally i found this which **does the reverse of what you are asking**, it highlights everything but the ip addressses,  go figure....

use:  \s.*   in the find dialog instead.

[Replace everything in the text file after IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270319/replace-everything-in-the-text-file-after-ip-address)

Now all you have to do to identify your ip addresses is ignore anything highlighted.

Note this also requires the ip address to be the first thing on a line, so you may have to 
Doctor your server logs to match this or tweak the regular expression for your specific needs.

Comment: You could assign a macro to the above so that you can apply your syntax highlight via a keyboard shortcut

Comment: Thanks Aaron H, I will accept your answer, was in doubt that it was not possible through a language. Works great, except regexp also highlights partial date&time (e.g. 07/Aug/**2014:10:26**:51) and HTTP response, but this is only a plus, really.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the regular expression that only highlights valid IPv4 addresses (taken from the same website mentioned above by Aaron H)

`\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(?1)){3}\b`

(notice the single character difference from accepted answer, seems that SO formatting dropped backslash character)